# Как склеить скрипт и иконку

Tags: python, файлы

Я имею python скрипт и иконку. Проблема в том что мне нужна иконка и одновременно нужно чтобы скрипт помещался в один файл. Я пробовал склеить скрипт и иконку через *File Joiner*, по итогу интерпретатор не может прочитать файл.

Вопрос, как мне склеить скрипт и иконку в один файл и при этом чтобы интерпретатор мог ее прочитать.

Ошибка: This file seems to have problems with encoding. Make sure it is in  UTF-8 or contains proper encoding hint.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: что такое "python программа"?

Comment: Чат-бот GPT с лёгкостью ответит на этот вопрос.